# Got stuck while make a ML model from scratch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a CSV file of various persons with 8 parameters to determine whether the person is diabetic or not.
You will get the CSV file from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/diabetes.csv)

I am making a model that will train and predict if a person is diabetic or not without using of third-party applications like Tensorlfow Scikitlearn etc. I am making it from scratch.

here is my code:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np

my_data = genfromtxt('E:/diabaties.csv', delimiter=',')

X,Y = my_data[1: ,:-1], my_data[1: ,-1:] #striping data and output from my_data


def sigmoid(x):
    return (1/(1+np.exp(-x)))

m = X.shape[0]
def propagate(W, b, X, Y):

    #forward propagation
    A = sigmoid(np.dot(X, W) + b)
    cost = (- 1 / m) * np.sum(Y * np.log(A) + (1 - Y) * (np.log(1 - A)))
    print(cost)

    #backward propagation
    dw = (1 / m) * np.dot(X.T, (A - Y))
    db = (1 / m) * np.sum(A - Y)
    return(dw, db, cost)

def optimizer(W,b,X,Y,number_of_iterration,learning_rate):
    for i in range(number_of_iterration):
        dw, db, cost = propagate(W,b,X,Y)
        W = W - learning_rate*dw
        b = b - learning_rate*db
    return(W, b)

W = np.zeros((X.shape[1],1))
b = 0
W,b = optimizer(W, b, X, Y, 100, 0.05)
```

The output which is getting generated is:
[It is in this link please take a look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogry5.jpg)

I have tried to -
initialize the value of W with random numbers.
spent a lot of time to debug but cannot find what I have done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short answer is that your learning rate is about 500x too big for this problem.  Think about it like you're trying to pilot your `W` vector into a canyon in the cost function.  At each step, the gradient tells you which way is down hill, but the steps you take in that direction are so big that you jump over the canyon and end up on the other side.  Each time this happens, your cost goes up because you're getting farther and farther out of the canyon until after 2 iterations, it blows up.

If you replace the line
`W,b = optimizer(W, b, X, Y, 100, 0.05)`

with

`W,b = optimizer(W, b, X, Y, 100, 0.0001)`

It will converge, though still not at a reasonable speed.  (Side note, there's no good way to know the learning rate you need for a given problem.  You just try lower and lower values until your cost value doesn't diverge.)

The longer answer is that the problem is that your features are all on different scales.

```
col_means = X.mean(axis=0)
col_stds = X.std(axis=0)
print('column means: ', col_means)
print('column stdevs: ', col_stds)
```

yields

```
column means:  [  3.84505208 120.89453125  69.10546875  20.53645833  79.79947917
  31.99257812   0.4718763   33.24088542]
column stdevs:  [  3.36738361  31.95179591  19.34320163  15.94182863 115.16894926
   7.87902573   0.33111282  11.75257265]
```

This means that the variations in the numbers of the second feature are about 100x as large as the variations in the numbers of the second to last feature which in turn means that the number of the second value in your `W` vector will have to be tuned to about 100x the precision of the value of the second to last number in your `W` vector.

There are two ways to deal with this in practice.  First, you could use a fancier optimizer.  Instead of basic gradient descent, you could use gradient descent with momentum, but that would change all your code.  The second, simpler, way is just to scale your features so they're all about the same size.

```
col_means = X.mean(axis=0)
col_stds = X.std(axis=0)
print('column means: ', col_means)
print('column stdevs: ', col_stds)
X -= col_means
X /= col_stds
W, b = optimizer(W, b, X, Y, 100, 1.0)
```

Here we subtract the mean value of each feature and divide each feature's value by its standard deviation.  Sometimes newbies are thrown off by this -- "you can't change your data values, that changes the problem" -- but it makes sense if you realize that it's just another mathematical transformation, just like multiplying by W, adding b, taking the sigmoid, etc.  The only catch is that you've got to make sure you do the same thing for any future data.  Just like the values of your `W` vector are learned parameters of your model, the values of the `col_means` and `col_stds` are too, so you've got to save them like `W` and `b` and use them if you want to perform inference with this model on new data in the future.

That lets us use a much bigger learning rater of 1.0 because now all the features are approximately the same size.

Now if you try, you'll get the following output:

```
column means:  [  3.84505208 120.89453125  69.10546875  20.53645833  79.79947917
  31.99257812   0.4718763   33.24088542]
column stdevs:  [  3.36738361  31.95179591  19.34320163  15.94182863 115.16894926
   7.87902573   0.33111282  11.75257265]
0.6931471805599452
0.5902957589079032
0.5481784378158732
0.5254804089153315
...
0.4709931321295562
0.4709931263193595
0.47099312122176273
0.4709931167488006
0.470993112823447
```

This is what you want.  Your cost function is going down at each step and at the end of your 100 iterations, the cost is stable to ~8 significant figures, so dropping it more probably won't do much.

Welcome to machine learning!

Comment: Thanks, man it works the explanation which you have done is quite alien to me as I don't have that much knowledge but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your initialization of the weight and bias. It’s important that you don’t initialize at least the weights to zero and instead initialize them with some random small numbers. The value of A is coming out to be zero making your cost function undefined

Update:

Try something like this:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np

# my_data = genfromtxt('E:/diabaties.csv', delimiter=',')

# X,Y = my_data[1: ,:-1], my_data[1: ,-1:] #striping data and output from my_data
# Using random data
n_points = 100
n_neurons = 5
X = np.random.rand(n_points, n_neurons) # 5 dimensional data from uniform distribution [0, 1)
Y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(n_points, 1)) # Binary labels

def sigmoid(x):
    return (1/(1+np.exp(-x)))

m = X.shape[0]
def propagate(W, b, X, Y):

    #forward propagation
    A = sigmoid(np.dot(X, W) + b)
    cost = (- 1 / m) * np.sum(Y * np.log(A) + (1 - Y) * (np.log(1 - A)))
    print(cost)

    #backward propagation
    dw = (1 / m) * np.dot(X.T, (A - Y))
    db = (1 / m) * np.sum(A - Y)
    return(dw, db, cost)

def optimizer(W,b,X,Y,number_of_iterration,learning_rate):
    for i in range(number_of_iterration):
        dw, db, cost = propagate(W,b,X,Y)
        W = W - learning_rate*dw
        b = b - learning_rate*db
    return(W, b)

W = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01, size=(n_neurons, 1))  # Drawing random initialization from gaussian
b = 0
W,b = optimizer(W, b, X, Y, 100, 0.05)
```

Comment: according to you, I have to initialize the value of W by some small values so I have initialized W by- W = np.random.randn(X.shape[1],1) , but it does not help at all the output is still the same. but thanks for the reply.

Comment: This is correct (bias can be initialized to zero, but weights never should) - it would be great if you could provide 1-liner of code to be used in place of `W = np.zeros((X.shape[1],1))`.

Comment: @KIVUOS try with a smaller variance (~ 0.01) - the default one of `1` is **huge** ;)

Comment: @desertnaut I have initialized W with `W = np.random.randn(X.shape[1],1)*0.01` but still, the problem remains. Is there something wrong with the code.

Comment: @KIVUOS I've updated the answer. You can try something like this to get started but how well this works in practice depends on lots of other things. Maybe try going through these links https://www.deeplearning.ai/ai-notes/initialization/ https://towardsdatascience.com/weight-initialization-techniques-in-neural-networks-26c649eb3b78

Comment: @piyush kansal  I have gone through the code which you have modified and as I can see that for the dataset which you have made the algorithm works fine but it is **still not working** with my data set I don't know why but thanks for your help.

Comment: @KIVOUS you will need to provide more context on why it's not working. Is it some errors or the loss is not going down. If its a different problem, then please open a new question and close this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your NaN problem is simply due to `np.log` encountering a zero value. You always want to scale your X values. Statistical (mean, std) normalization will work, but I find min-max scaling works best. Here is code for that:

```
def minmax_scaler(x):
    min = np.nanmin(x, axis=0)
    max = np.nanmax(x, axis=0)
    return (x-min)/(max-min)
```

Also, your neural net has only one neuron. When you call `np.dot(X, W)` these should be matrices of shape (cases, features) and (features, neurons) respectively. So, now your initialization code looks like this:

```
X = minmax_scaler(X)
neurons = 10
learning_rate = 0.05
W = np.random.random((X.shape[1], neurons)) 
b = np.zeros((1, neurons)) # b width to match W
```

I got decent convergence without needing to change the learning rate.  See chart:

[image: Cost value converges]

This is such a small dataset that, even with 10-20 neurons, you are in danger of overfitting it. Ordinarily, you would code a predict() method and an accuracy check, and then set aside some of the data to test for overfitting.